# Facing Javascript bubbling in case of server sent event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, server-sent-events, event-bubbling

Think of HTML5 server sent event(I am using php in server side). To get server sent data I have this code:

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("chat.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
       $(document).click(function(){
          alert(event.data);
       });
    };
}
```

Where `chat.php` sends some data `every 4 seconds`. `1st 4 second`(i.e. 0 sec to 4 sec) clicking on page I get `1 alert`. `2nd 4 seconds`(i.e. 4+ sec to 8 sec) clicking on page I get alert `2 times`. `3rd 4 seconds`(i.e. 8+ sec to 12 sec) I get alert `3 times`.......and so on.

Notice that, this is something like javascript bubling. Any idea to get rid of this?

`Edit:` (I am adding more)

server side code:

```
<?php
    echo "data: $customers\n\n";
    /* value of $customers is produced by some query */
    flush();
    sleep(1);
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use client side ajax requests to request an update?

Comment: @ Michael Dibbets  thats a great suggestion, then i have to do it inside setInterval(). because i have to be updated all  time. Would it be a good idea? ajax call inside setInterval() ? what do you think?

Comment: I would not use a setInterval because you sort of lose flexibility to make the delay longer or shorter when needed. I would make a new timeout everytime to which I'd safe the reference, that so if need be I can cancel the last timeout. Basically it'd be a self calling function within the timeout. If you really want to be life synced with your server with minimal overhead i'd go with a websocket https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=websocket%20server Then you can just push changes as soon as they occur

Comment: yes, your idea deserves to be thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to `event Bubbling`. This is from the server side `datas` that you are sending, the problem is you are sending the datas from the beginning after every 4 secs.

The solution is to send only the required data for **that particular** four seconds and the empty the `data` variable in your server side file

It  would be useful if you could also post the `PHP` file from which you are sending datas

Comment: yes, I am doing that every 4 seconds, because I need to be updated all time, any time server data may be modified. I cannot send data only a particular four seconds.